# How do I acquire a fresh access_token with the refresh_token after the access_token has expired?

Tags: access-token, django-allauth

Some providers let you acquire a fresh access_token without user interaction provided the application's permissions have not been withdrawn by the user.

How do I trigger this from allauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that as of 29/8/16 there is an open issue on the project to add this functionality, so it doesn't exist yet.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/420